# Java JAX-WS subelement as element value

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Let's say I want to have single field element in Root parent.

```
<Root>
   <something>HELLO</something>
</Root>
```

This can be simply achived with:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
public class WSRoot
{
   @XmlElement(name="something")
   private String something = "HELLO";

   public WSRoot() {}
}
```

Now I want to set some functionality to the 'something' class
(which is String in above example)
Since java standard classes (Long,String) are:
- immutable (I cannot change value instead to set it with another reference)
- final (I cannot extend it with my own methods)
the only solution is to create own class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
public class WSRoot
{
   @XmlElement(name="something")
   private WSString something = new WSString();

   public WSRoot() {}
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class WSString 
{
   @XmlElement(name="value")
   private String value = "HELLO";

   public WSString() {}
}
```

Now the result is as expected:

```
<Root>
   <something>
      <value>HELLO</value>
   </something>
</Root>
```

My question is, does JAX-WS have some trick, that you can tell
my class has only ONE element and its value I want to set as value in
Root element, not creating subelement 'value'

Let me explain in detail why I need this.
I have my WSString class (which has some other properties and functionality).
I also want to be initialized in the constructor immediately, as I add this
to a list for further functionality

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
public class WSRoot extends WSCommon
{
   @XmlAttribute(name="var1")
   private WSString var1 = new WSString();

   @XmlAttribute(name="var2")
   private WSString var2 = new WSString();

   public WSRoot() {
       super(var1, var2,...)
   }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class WSString 
{
   @XmlValue
   private String value ;

   public WSString() {}

   ...setters/getters...
}
```

One way to get rid of 'something' from created element would be, that I set something to 'null',
but I dont want this (I want 'value' in WSString to be for this)

So, in case:

```
var1.setValue("This");
var2.setValue("That");
```

gives me properly

```
<Root var1="This" var2="That"/>
```

If I would do:

```
var1.setValue("This");
var2.setValue(null);
```

I would logically expect result

```
<Root var1="This"/>
```

but in this case I get @XmlValue null exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your WSString class in this way:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class WSString
{
    @XmlValue
    private String value = "HELLO";

    public WSString() {}
}
```

Using the **XmlValue** annotation the result will be:

```
<Root>
    <something>HELLO</something>
</Root>
```

**UPDATE:**

Using ***WSRoot.java***:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
public class WSRoot {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "var1")
    private WSString var1 = new WSString();

    @XmlAttribute(name = "var2")
    private WSString var2 = new WSString();

    public WSRoot() {
    }

    public WSString getVar1() {
        return var1;
    }

    public void setVar1(WSString var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

    public WSString getVar2() {
        return var2;
    }

    public void setVar2(WSString var2) {
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

}
```

and ***WSString.java***:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class WSString {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    public WSString() {
        this.value = "";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

If you create:

```
WSRoot root = new WSRoot();
root.getVar1().setValue("THIS");
root.getVar2().setValue("THAT");
```

as you expect you will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root var1="THIS" var2="THAT"/>
```

If you do:

```
WSRoot root = new WSRoot();
root.getVar1().setValue("THIS");
root.getVar2().setValue(null);
```

this is wrong because value is defined as *@XmlValue*.
You have to set Var2 to **null** instead of its value:

```
WSRoot root = new WSRoot();
root.getVar1().setValue("THIS");
root.setVar2(null);
```

This because Var2 is *@XmlAttribute* and JAXB does not parse null value, so in this way you will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root var1="THIS"/>
```

**Moreover:**

Applying some modify to WSRoot.java you can simplify the process to assign the null values to Var2 or Var2Value. 
For example, you can add these methods that will set the WSString value direclty from WSRoot in the right way for you:

```
public void setVar1Value(String value) {
    if(value == null) {
        this.var1 = null;
    } else {
        this.var1.setValue(value);
    }
}

public void setVar2Value(String value) {
    if(value == null) {
        this.var2 = null;
    } else {
        this.var2.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

But as you can see all null values will be assigned to WSString object and not to its value, so if you do:

```
WSRoot root = new WSRoot();
root.setVar1Value("THIS");
root.setVar2Value("THAT");
```

You will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root var1="THIS" var2="THAT"/>
```

If you do:

```
WSRoot root = new WSRoot();
root.setVar1Value("THIS");
root.setVar2Value(null);
```

Now the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root var1="THIS"/>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Since "JAXB (and XML) does not represent null as an empty element" you could inizialize `this.value = "";` in the WSString constructor.

Comment: Then I will get output as na element. With 'null' value I want to avoid this and toggle whether the element would be created or not (as jaxb with 'null' object does)

Comment: You can't with XmlValue!

Comment: That's why I'm asking if there is another trick :)

(I updated answer with some more details.)
It could be easily achieved with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter,
but adapters makes another reference to the variable (loosing
previously added to the list)

Comment: Did you try `@XmlElement(name="value", nillable=true)` in your WSString?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use xml element name in WSString since its generic class used for many attributes

Comment: Setting var2 to null will loose reference to the list created in the Root constructor :(

I have this way cause all parameter checking processing etc..
is made by generic complex process (WSString actually holds also name, references to database fields etc...)
Also 'Root' object holds the database references etc..
Usually I do straight webservices (with regular strings), but this time I have 50+ db tables which changes from time to time, and the model
works great (with almost no code, just fields), except this 'null' issue :P

Voodoo, thx for help anyway :)